# Multiple functions and callbacks in a custom jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, callback

Okay I'm not sure if I'm going about this in the right way or not, but here goes...

I'm writing a custom jQuery plugin to provide drop menu functionality with animation (and as a learning exercise so please no "Why not just use *superduperwonderplugin-x*").

I want to be able to animate the menu in different ways depending on user options (i.e fade, slide, drop etc.). At the moment each different animation is handled by a separate function within the plugin file but I'm not sure how to handle the callback functions (passing *this* back)!

-- i.e. The animation is only happening on the last element in the object's stack.

Here's my code:

```
/**
 * Grizzly's Menuifier
 * 
 * @author  Chris.Leaper
 * @version a1.0
 */
(function($){
    $.fn.gmenu = function(options) {

        /* Transitions:
            - fade >> fadeIn / fadeOut
            - slide >> slideDown / slideUp
            - drop >> (different to above?)
            - bounce >> (custom config transition=? and easing=bounce)
            - stretch >> (custom config transition=? and easing=elastic)
            - fold >> (custom) drop menu @ half width then 'fold' out to full menu width
        */

        // Set the plugin default options:
        var defaults = {
            levels: '1',
            fit: 'auto',
            easing: 'linear',
            transition: 'slide',
            speed: 500
        };

        options = $.extend(defaults, options); // Merge the user options with the plugin defaults

        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var opt = options;
            var container;
            var ul;

            // Setup the container elements (parent DIV/NAV and UL)!
            if( $this.is('ul') ) container = $(this).parent();
            else container = $(this);

            console.log('Container: ' + container.get(0).tagName + ' id=#' + container.attr('id') + ' class=' + container.attr('class'));

            ul = container.children('ul:first-child');

            console.log('UL: ' + ul);

            // Set the UL's position to relative:
            if($(ul).css('position') != 'relative') $(ul).css('position', 'relative');

            var offset;
            var menus = ul.children('li:has(ul)');

            console.log('List Item: ' + menus);

            menus.each(function(index, menu) {
                $menu = $(menu);

                console.log('Menu: ' + $menu);

                // Set the menu LI's position to relative (contains the absolutely positioned child UL!)
                if($menu.css('position') != 'relative') $menu.css('position', 'relative');

                // Get the menu LI's position relative to the document (it's offset)
                // -- This is only needed when positioning non-child elements
                // (i.e. ID linked menu>submenu relationships as may be used for a separated DIV based menu!!)
//              offset = menu.offest();

                // Position the submenu according to it's parent
                var submenu = $menu.children('ul');

                console.log('Submenu: ' + submenu.get(0).tagName + ' id=#' + submenu.attr('id') + ' class=' + submenu.attr('class'));

                setPosition(submenu, $menu.height());

                switch(opt.transition) {
                    case 'bounce':
                        setSMBounce(menu, opt);
                        break;
                    case 'fade':
                        setSMFade(menu, opt);
                        break;
                    case 'fold':
                        setSMFold(menu, opt);
                        break;
                    case 'stretch':
                        setSMStretch(menu, opt);
                        break;
                    case 'slide':
                    default:
                        menu = setSMSlide(menu, opt);
                }
            });

            debug(this);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

function setPosition(submenu, height) {
    $(submenu).css({
        left: 0,
        position: 'absolute',
        top: height
    }).hide();
}

function setSMSlide(menu, opt) {
    $menu = $(menu);

    console.log('SM Slide: ' + $menu.get(0));

    $menu.first('a').mouseenter(function() {
        console.log('Start SlideDown');
        $menu.stop(true, true).slideDown(opt.speed, opt.easing);
        console.log('Stop SlideDown');
    });

    $menu.first('a').mouseleave(function() {
        console.log('Start SlideUp');
        $menu.stop(true, true).slideUp(opt.speed, opt.easing);
        console.log('Stop SlideUp');
    });
}
```

I think that I should be using a (same) namespace based approach to defining my separate functions (*object literal or something?*) but I wasn't sure what this meant or how to do it.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To encapsulate your functions *setPosition* and *setSMSlide* (in your example) just define them inside your plugin function (the good place would be after definition of default variable. It would look something like that:

```
var defaults = {
        levels: '1',
        fit: 'auto',
        easing: 'linear',
        transition: 'slide',
        speed: 500
    },
    setPosition = function(submenu, height) {...},
    setSMSlide = function(menu, opt) {...};
```

Because of the way the scoping in Javascript works your setPosition and setSMSlide functions will be still accessible from inside of your gmenu declaration.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try. Would this make them accessible as '$(selector).gmenu.setPosition();'?

Comment: No it wouldn't. Because what you're returning from the function (the gmenu one) is a jQuery object - which in general is a good thing and is a common design pattern to enable chaining. There are of course many plugins out there that don't follow that rule for many reasons. I think it would be best for you to just take a glance at source code of couple of plugins to see how they're organized. That's the beauty of Javascript - you can peek and reverse-engineer every script :)